# Display Lists vs immediate rendering

Tags: opengl, frame-rate, displaylist, immediate-mode

I am trying to find if display list has better fps than immediate rendering. From what I found online display lists are faster, But I found some code online and it that situation immediate mode is faster?
Can anyone explain me which one has better fps and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Display lists will be *much* faster than immediate mode. They buffer the drawing commands sent to OpenGL and allow execution from the GPU itself. They are quire flexible in that they buffer quite a variety of commands. I believe you can even nest them. They are quite easy to set up, so it wouldn't take long to benchmark the difference.

Display lists are however, deprecated, so you should be looking at rendering with *vertex buffer objects* (VBOs) and `glDraw*()` unless it's just for fun.